How to handle statusCallback in Twilio client using TNetHTTPRequest?
I am using Twilio client to make phone calls with C++Builder (RAD Studio Tokyo) 10.2.3 and Intraweb 15.
To handle callbacks, this is the solution suggested by Twilio tech team:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#set-statuscallback-on-an-outbound-call
 async function createCall() {
  const call = await client.calls.create({
    from: "+18668675310",
    method: "GET",
    statusCallback: "https://www.myapp.com/events",
    statusCallbackMethod: "POST",
    to: "+14155551212",
    url: "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
  });

  console.log(call.sid);
} 

The statusCallback is supposed to be a URL back to the web application built with Intraweb.
Using the Delphi Twilio Client, the phone call is made this way:
https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/twilio-delphi-demo/blob/master/TwilioClient.pas
allParams := TStringList.Create;
allParams.Add('From=' + fromPhoneNumber);
allParams.Add('To=' + toPhoneNumber);
allParams.Add('Url=http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml');

response := client.Post('Calls', allParams); 

The Twilio client is just a TNetHTTPRequest.
The problem is how to use the TNetHTTPRequest to handle the statusCallback so that I can get the result of the call back to my application?

OK. Thanks for the response

You don't handle the events with TNetHTTPRequest itself. It is just an HTTP client, it can't receive events, that is not how HTTP works (at least not in this case). Twilio will post separate HTTP requests to the specified callback URL, so you need an active HTTP server running at that URL to receive the events asynchronously, outside of your request.
